# OpenGL transformations

Tags: c++, opengl

I have an object at a point, say x,y,z with respect to the origin.
I want to apply some transformations to the point, say rotation and translation, and render the object at the transformed point. I'm using the `glTranslatef()` and `glRotatef()` functions. It looks some what like this:

```
glTranslatef(x,y,z); 
glRotatef(Ang,0,1,0); // rotated around Y axis at an arbitrary angle
glTranslatef(xt,yt,zt); // further translation
<render the object>
```

Even though it saves me from the complicated matrix transformation operations, I'm unaware of the actual coordinate values  of the final position with respect to the origin. Is there a method to retrieve the actual position coordinates of the transformed point without going through the matrix operations?

Comment: what do you want to do - to draw the object at given coordinates, or to draw it as in your example, but somehow know where it ends up?

Comment: i need to draw an object at the transformed position ,as well as know the transformed coordinates, for a calculation..

Comment: @flopcoder Why did you undo most of my edits, introducing corrected problems back into the question? For example, it's OpenGL, NOT OpenGl

Comment: @Bart Oops, we were editing this simultaneously, and I didn't edit that. I don't have edit privilege, so my edits were pending.

Comment: @FlopCoder Ah, that might explain it. I'll update

Answer (score 13):

I'll give you some theory first. OpenGL works with matrices `4x4` and vectors (point coordinates) with length of `4` (in 3D).

Let's have a vector `X = (x,y,z,1)`. I hope you know how to [multiply matrixes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication). And let's say that you want to translate your point by
`V = (vx,vy,vz)`.
To do that you'll need to build [translation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_matrix) like this:

[image: Translation matrix]

And you'll multiply two matrices (matrix * vector/point) : `Y = TX`:

[image: Translation via matrix]

The reason to do this so complicatedly (and not just add `X + V`) is that you can rotate your point around the axis just by filling the same matrix with different values. It's called a [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix):

[image: Rotation matrices]

The best part is that you can chain those matrices. When you need to draw point with those rules:

- Translate `T1`
- Rotate `R1`
- Translate `T2`

You can prepare one matrix which will do all the work at once:
`F = 
T1R1T2`

And than apply all those transformations to the point at once: `Y = FX`.

Please note that matrix multiplication is not [commutative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) so **order does matter**.

OpenGL works with those matrices (there are few more types like [scale matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_matrix)) internally. You can get current transformation matrix with command (example from [here](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/game-development/threads/191233)):

```
glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, redTransformationMatrix);
```

And here's how to represent those data correctly (detailed info [here](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html)):

[image]

<sub>All images except the last one are taken from [wikipedia.org](http://en.wikipedia.org/)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve the matrices from the OpenGL state using [glGetDoublev](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGet.xml):

```
GLdouble projectionMatrix[16];
glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION, projectionMatrix);

GLdouble modelViewMatrix[16];
glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW, modelViewMatrix);
```

Also note, that when you translate first and then rotate, you are rotating the translation vector, too.
Normally, you rotate the object in the origin and then translate it, thus resulting in a rotated object at the translation end-point.

**EDIT:** To get the transformed coordinates *p'*, you need to transform a point *p* using those matrices:

```
p' = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * p
```

I suggest using [glm](http://glm.g-truc.net/) for these kind of operations.